# Make the size of overlay container same as image inside

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

There are images. In this example it has a `width: 320px;` and a `height: 200px;`. The **overlay** is working fine with:

```
.overlay-content {
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  ...
}
```

But I **can't** set declarations of the image, like

```
img {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do it without knowing the width and the height in `.overlay-content` and without setting declarations to the `<img>` ?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1cd0bdw/), and the corresponding example:

```css
img {
  /* You can't do anything here */
}
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}
.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;
  /* This you don't know */
  width: 320px;
  /* This you don't know */
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
.overlay-content div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;
  background: orange;
  transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay-content div ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.overlay-content div ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 33.3333%;
  width: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.overlay-content div ul li span,
.overlay-content div ul li a {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: yellow;
}
.overlay:hover > .overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
.overlay:hover > .overlay-content div {
  width: 50%;
}
.overlay:hover > .overlay-content div ul li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" />
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a>
        </li>
        <li><span>Second</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Third</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/320x200" />
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">First</a>
        </li>
        <li><span>Second</span>
        </li>
        <li><span>Third</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the overlay as `display:inline-block;` or `display:table;`, so that the size of it will be the same as the image, as `.overlay-content` is set as absolute position it's out of the normal content flow.

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  ...
}
```

And the overlay content as:

```
.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  ...
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx2u38bf/)**